# How to use custom syntax highlighter styles in DocBook 5.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, docbook

I have syntax highlighting on a docbook using a custom language highlighter based on the c++ example.

How can I use different styles for the same highlighter type?

for instance:

```
<highlighter type="keywords">

<keyword>char</keyword>

<keyword>const</keyword>

<keyword>double</keyword>

<keyword>true</keyword>
<style>keyword</style>

</highlighter>

<highlighter type="keywords">

<keyword>Hotspot</keyword>

<keyword>Character</keyword>

<keyword>Region</keyword>
<style>class</style>
```

the second load of keywords should highlight with the style 'class' but how do I define and test for this non-default style?

Comment: Your question is not clear. We don't know if you are talking about DocBook vocabulary, a DocBook Editor, a conversion stylesheet from DocBook to other format. Plus, your answer is an XSLT rule matching an `xslthl:class` wich is not present into your input sample. This won't help anybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
 <xsl:template match='xslthl:class' mode="xslthl">
 <b style="color: green"><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
 </xsl:template>
```

the 'mode' attribute seems vital